# Alternative to AbsoluteLayout

Tags: android, absolutelayout

the question "What is a *usefull* alternative to AbsoluteLayout?" seems to be a question which is often asked, but never really answered. My situation is as follows:

I want to position Circles (for the sake of simplicity i used RadioButtons for testing) so that the distances between the circles are proportional on all possible display sizes.

Also i need to know the position of the circles to match onTouchEvent.

This seems fairly easy with AbsoluteLayout since i can get (at runtime) the defaultDisplay's width and height and so i can position Objects in an AbsoluteLayout relative to the display metrics.

Now I want to avoid AbsoluteLayout for obvious reasons, but RelativeLayout doesn't seem to be an alternative since - as far as i know - one can only say "put that object right next to that other object" or below or whatever. How to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my Opinion the best way to achieve your goal is to use the [Canvas](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html) and draw everything yourself. In the Canvas you have the information of the screen at runtime and you have full control of the things to draw.

Comment: thanks for your answer. i actually found a tutorial now for canvas which i understood. Seems to be the best alternative but still not perfect. For those of you interested in the tutorial i mentioned: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rBtIRTqwnRI

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to draw your own shapes (and handle all normal touch events) and do not need other UI Widgets on the same view, then use `Canvas`.

If you do need Widgets on this view then your only option is `AbsoluteLayout`.